# How to pass a dict argument to Python Pool.apply_async method?

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing

I need to pass a dict to Python Pool.apply_async. It doesn't seem to work as expected because my script get stuck. How to pass a dict argument to Python Pool.apply_async method?

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def my_func(session, index):
    result = { "server": session['server'], "exit_code": session['exit_code'],"index": index }  
    return result
        
def my_callback(result):
    print(result)

pool = mp.Pool(5)

sessions = []
sessions.append({"server": "foo.tld", "exit_code": 1})
sessions.append({"server": "bar.tld", "exit_code": 0})

for i, session in enumerate(sessions):
    # Below, "session" argument is a dict
    pool.apply_async(my_func, kwds={ "session": session, "index": i}, callback=my_callback)
        
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: What di you mean by "get stuck". What platform are you running on?

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep the [`AsyncResult`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) object returned from `apply_async`, and call its `get` method, like this:

```py
for i, session in enumerate(sessions):
    res = pool.apply_async(my_func,  kwds={ "session": session, "index": i}, callback=my_callback)
    print(res.get())
```

Output should be something like:

```
{'server': 'foo.tld', 'exit_code': 1, 'index': 0}
{'server': 'foo.tld', 'exit_code': 1, 'index': 0}
{'server': 'bar.tld', 'exit_code': 0, 'index': 1}
{'server': 'bar.tld', 'exit_code': 0, 'index': 1}
```

check out the [example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) in the docs

Comment: thanks but this doesn't solve the issue. Problem is with "session" argument which is a dict not being handled properly. If I only pass "index" arg (integer) to "test_func", the script is not stuck anymore. Perhaps I migth try to serialize/unserialize the "session" argument but wanted to avoid this in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

This simplified (`with`, `imap_unordered`) version works just fine for me.

Always remember to wrap the main multiprocessing entrypoint in a function.

```
import multiprocessing as mp


def my_func(arg):
    index, session = arg
    result = {
        "server": session["server"],
        "exit_code": session["exit_code"],
        "index": index,
    }
    return result


def main():
    sessions = [
        {"server": "foo.tld", "exit_code": 1},
        {"server": "bar.tld", "exit_code": 0},
    ]
    with mp.Pool(5) as pool:

        for res in pool.imap_unordered(my_func, enumerate(sessions)):
            print(res)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate on why use "imap_unordered" instead apply_async plus why wrapping the entrypoint in a function (aka "main")? Also note that I tried to modify my code with serializing/deserializing the "session" argument passed to apply_async and it worked.

Comment: Because `imap_unordered` does the work of enqueueing work and receiving results in batches for you. As to why `main`, because [the manual tells you to](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming).

Answer (score 0):

All you said was, "my script get stuck", which is not very descriptive. You also did not tag your question with the platform on which you are running, such as `linux` or `windows`, as you are supposed to do when you post questions tagged with `multiprocessing`. That leaves me guessing that your problem arises from running on Windows. If so, the issue is that Windows uses a method called `spawn` to create new processes. This means to create the processes in the multiprocessing pool and invoke your worker function, `my_func`, a new empty address space is created and a new Python interpreter is launched that initializes the process by re-reading your source program executing every statement at global scope.

So all import statements, function definitions, data declarations, executable statements, etc. at global scope will be executed. The only difference for the newly created process is that whereas in the main process internal variable `__name__` has the value `'__main__'`, it will not have this value for these subprocesses. This allows you to place within blocks that test the value of `__name__` any statements that you do not want executed by the initialization of the subprocesses. Such statements would be the actual executable statements that create the subprocesses. If you do not place these statements within a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block, then you would get into a recursive loop creating new processes *ad infinitum* (actually Python recognizes this condition and throws an exception instead).

So typically you place code that creates new processes within a function such as `main` (choose any name you want) and make sure that `main` is only called  conditionally based on the value of `__name__`:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Or you can keep the process-creation code at global scope but within an `if __name__ == '__main__':` block:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

def my_func(session, index):
    result = { "server": session['server'], "exit_code": session['exit_code'],"index": index }
    return result

def my_callback(result):
    print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(5)

    sessions = []
    sessions.append({"server": "foo.tld", "exit_code": 1})
    sessions.append({"server": "bar.tld", "exit_code": 0})

    for i, session in enumerate(sessions):
        # Below, "session" argument is a dict
        pool.apply_async(my_func, kwds={ "session": session, "index": i}, callback=my_callback)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Prints:

```
{'server': 'foo.tld', 'exit_code': 1, 'index': 0}
{'server': 'bar.tld', 'exit_code': 0, 'index': 1}
```

Note that I also placed *all* executable statements, such as the creation of the `sessions` list, which are not required to be executed by the subprocesses within the `if __name__ == '__main__':` for efficiency.

It is just "neater", however, to code as follows:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

def my_func(session, index):
    result = { "server": session['server'], "exit_code": session['exit_code'],"index": index }
    return result

def my_callback(result):
    print(result)

def main():
    pool = mp.Pool(5)

    sessions = []
    sessions.append({"server": "foo.tld", "exit_code": 1})
    sessions.append({"server": "bar.tld", "exit_code": 0})

    for i, session in enumerate(sessions):
        # Below, "session" argument is a dict
        pool.apply_async(my_func, kwds={ "session": session, "index": i}, callback=my_callback)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```